# Adding a project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In Visual Studio (C#) I have a form created as part of a project and need to have access to another form that should be created through another project and have both forms reference each other when necessary.. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Did the accepted answer work for you?  If you have two projects each trying to reference forms in the other then I would have expected you to have gotten a circular dependency error when you attempted to set the project references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can right click on the project name in project explorer window. And choose Add Reference. In the Add Reference window, choose "Projects" tab and select the project you wish to reference to. Do the same for another project. They should now can reference each other.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on References in your project and select "Add Reference", then add another project as reference.

Answer (score 0):

If these are in different assemblies, then you are going to have a circular reference, which is disallowed. Visual Studio will give you an error message when you try to add the second reference. The real solution to this problem is to introduce an abstraction (assuming you can't just go ahead and put them into the same assembly, that is).

[Here's the best write-up I've ever found about the issue.](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/dip.pdf) Hope it helps.